# MongoServerError: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

I'm running on mongodb atlas, on the free M0 cluster tier.

When trying to make a transaction, I'm faced with this error:

```
MongoServerError: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos
```

I've tried the transaction in the two approaches below.

On many places mongodb atlas convey transactions are supported ([like here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs--mongodb--how-to-implement-transactions)), and that it should just "work".

So am I missing something here?

My connection string is :

```
mongodb+srv://USER:PASS@cluster0.6eiq4.mongodb.net/DB_NAME?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

1st approach

```
const session = await connection.startSession();
session.startTransaction();
try {
  const result = await SomeModel.create({ stuff }, { session });
  await session.commitTransaction();
  return result;
} catch (error) {
  console.log("abort transaction!", error);
  await session.abortTransaction();
} finally {
  await session.endSession();
}
```

2nd approach

```
const session = await connection.startSession();
session.withTransaction(async () => {
  try {
    const result = await SomeModel.create({ stuff }, { session });
    await session.commitTransaction();
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("abort transaction!", error);
    await session.abortTransaction();
  } finally {
    await session.endSession();
  }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Your missing `replicaSet=rs` in your connection string.